# How to deal wiith querydsl multiple schema have same table name?

Tags: java, querydsl

Simply I faced a problem when trying to access query DSL with multiple schemas, I added multiple schemas as below

```
<schemaPattern>ABC,DEF</schemaPattern>
```

and my table name pattern is

```
<tableNamePattern>PQR,STU</tableNamePattern>
```

suppose both schemas have DEF table then when I compile maven project it gives me the below error.

> Failed to execute goal com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export (default) on project TestProject:
> Execution default of goal com.querydsl:querydsl-maven-plugin:4.2.1:export failed: Attempted to write multiple times to D:\test\repos\testProject\target\generated-sources\testPackage\domain\dependency\QDEF.java, please check your configuration

Can anyone tell me a way to resolve this and also can explain how to access generated classes in specific schema(for example I want to declare QDEF qdet = QDEF.qdef , this is normal way, but how can I declare QDEF in STU schema)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was resolved [here](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/1793). It looks like `<schemaToPackage>true</schemaToPackage>` is what you need.